# Insert data into two tables in database with one to many relationships ASP.NET EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have a `Post` class

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public List<string> GalleryPaths { get; set; }
    }
```

And an `Image` class:

```
    public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PostId")]
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to add a `Post` to my Posts table and a `List<Image>` to my Images table.

My approach:

```
public void Create(PostAddRequest model)
        {
            List<string> galleryImageFiles = new List<string>();
            if (model.GalleryImages != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in model.GalleryImages)
                {
                    galleryImageFiles.Add("/Content/img/uploads/" + Guid.NewGuid() + "_" + model.FeaturedImage.FileName);
                    item.SaveAs(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(galleryImageFiles.Last()));
                }
            }
            var post = new Post()
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Content = model.Content,
            };
            model.FeaturedImage.SaveAs(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(featuredImageFile));
            _unitOfWork.PostRepository.AddPost(post);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

            List<Image> gallery = new List<Image>();
            foreach (var item in galleryImageFiles)
            {
                gallery.Add(new Image()
                {
                    Path = item,
                    PostId = post.Id
                });
            }
            _unitOfWork.ImageRepository.AddGallery(gallery);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm kinda new to EF and was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this, or even removing the need of a `ImageRepository`?

Comment: Your code is *breaking* Unit-of-Work (assuming your _unitofwork is a DbContext and all those repositories are really DbSet<>s). `SaveChanges` commits all pending changes, essentially completing the UoW, and thus should only be called before exiting the DbContext's scope

Comment: In general there's no need to put repositories and UoW implementations on top of EF Core. EF has already abstracted storage and implemented repositories and UoW.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this answer really helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32099279/19342899)

Posting my own solution:

```
public void Create(PostAddRequest model)
        {
            List<string> galleryImageFiles = new List<string>();
      
            if (model.GalleryImages != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in model.GalleryImages)
                {
                    galleryImageFiles.Add("/Content/img/uploads/" + Guid.NewGuid() + "_" + model.FeaturedImage.FileName);
                    item.SaveAs(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(galleryImageFiles.Last()));
                }
            }
            var post = new Post()
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Content = model.Content,
                GalleryPaths = new List<Image>()
            };

            _unitOfWork.PostRepository.AddPost(post);

            foreach (var item in galleryImageFiles)
            {
                post.GalleryPaths.Add(new Image()
                {
                    Path = item,
                    PostId = post.Id
                });
            }
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: What *is* the answer? What's changed? And where is the EF code? EF Core has no `UnitOfWork` or `Repository` classes. A DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work implementation. A DbSet is already a single-entity repository. The only thing I see is that the multiple erroneous `SaveChanges` calls were replaced with a single one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, the project I'm working on needs to have a 3 layer architecture(Web, BLL, DAL), so that's why I'm using repositories and `UnitOfWork`.

What I changed is that I removed the need for a separate `ImageRepository` by accessing images as `post.GalleryPaths.Add`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with layer. You already have both a UoW and repositories. They're called `DbContext` and `DbSet<>`