# EF 6 How to inset and update tables (one-to-many) relationship?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Candidate Table with one to many relationship with CandRemark table.

How to insert and update the Candremarks ICollection

```
public partial class Candidate
    {
        public Candidate()
        {
            Candremarks = new HashSet<Candremark>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<Candremark> Candremarks { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Candremark
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FkCandId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RemarkDate { get; set; }
        public string Remark { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual Candidate FkCand { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

So for **Insert** I have tried the following but I am not really sure how to add the syntax to add a new remark related to the candidate Candremarks ICollection.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 
                _dbContext.Candidates.AddAsync(new Candidate
                {
                    FirstName = "John",
                    MiddleName = "A",
                    LastName = "Sam",
    
/* Code here to add the New Remark for the new added candidate */
                    //= new Entities.Candremark
                    //{
                    //    RemarkDate = Convert.ToDateTime("08/11/2022"),
                    //    Remark = " Comments -------- 2"
                    //}
    
                });
                _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

How to update **Update** Candidate Remark. I have the following code but it seems not working, not updating the CandRemark table. The `_currCandEntity` is an instance of the current Entity Candidate

```
private void btnAddRemark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
                _currCandEntity.Candremarks.Add(new Candremark
                {
                    FkCandId = _currCandEntity.Id,
                    Remark = txtRemark.Text,
                    RemarkDate = d.Date
                }
                );
               _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a very common task, and there are many questions & answers on this site, along with tons of tutorials on other sites, that show you how to do it.  Please edit your question and add in your code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at answering your question.  Then explain at what point you aren't getting the result you expect.  If we don't understand what is unique about your problem and why the standard approaches aren't working, we can't help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert new/Update existing record with one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099045/insert-new-update-existing-record-with-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @devlincarnate Thank you for pointing this out. I will update my question to be specific